# Why can't I instantiate CrudRepository in @SpringBootTest for library without SpringBootApplication?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I have a simple CRUD repo I am trying to use in an Integration (IT) Test...

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, String> { }
```

So I create a simple Test to inject it...

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ItemRepository.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ItemRepoIT {
    @Autowired
    ItemRepository repo;

    @Test
    public void initialTest() throws JsonProcessingException {
      // do something with repo
    }
}
```

But when I run the test I get...

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
> Failed to instantiate [some.pkg.ItemRepository]: Specified class is an
> interface     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:70)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1310)
> ... 41 more

So how would Inject this into a test?

Comment: @SpringBootTest(classes = {ItemRepository.class}) Do you really want to apply just ItemRepository for context

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez So this is a library of Components that is embedded in other projects. I still want to be able to run some basic integration tests, but I can't use an entire SpringBootApplication or it conflicts later on (AFAIK)

Answer (score 2):

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class TestA {

    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;
 
    @Test
    public void test() {}

}
```

Application is the configuration class that will invoke all context. In your case please replace Application.class to main class or configuration class
It is JUnit5 also so you can replace ExtendWith to RunWith

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because when using `@SpringBootTest(classes=ItemRepository.class)`, you are looking to load a `@Configuration` class. Because you are loading an instant Repository (it is an interface extending a Repository provided by Spring Data), you need more classes to be loaded on the `ApplicationContext`.

You are running a SpringBoot project, that means you are supposed to have a class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. Why don't you try this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ItemRepoIT {
    @Autowired
    ItemRepository repo;

    @Test
    public void initialTest() throws JsonProcessingException {
      // do something with repo
    }
}
```

The default behaviour of `@SpringBootTest` is to look for the `@SpringBootConfiguration` (or the `@SpringBootApplication`) class in your class path.

You could try Slice testing with Spring. Here is an example:

```
@DataJpaTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ItemRepoIT {
    @Autowired
    ItemRepository repo;

    @Test
    public void initialTest() throws JsonProcessingException {
      // do something with repo
    }
}
```

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test).

Finally, in your situation, you could add a `@SpringBootApplication` in your test folder to have a fake application loading the entire class path.

Comment: This fails because this is a library and there is no SpringApplication

Comment: The Spring Application context initialization happens in a later project so I don't want one in here. Basically it is configs and repos that are shared.

Comment: then try using Slice testing, I'll update my answer

Comment: I think your question needs to be more specific. It is impossible for anyone to guess your particular situation where you are only developing a 'library'.

Comment: I agree but I didn't really know where the margins were to ask a good question. Let me test a few more things and try to come up with a better way to work it

Comment: Is there something similar when I am running JPA from a command line runner? I currently get issues with Instantiating repos that way too. I have a question for that but again the way I worded it needs work

Comment: I tried this and I get "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a \@SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or \@SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test" I tried adding back the SpringBootTest and got...

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [com.jpmc.cmp.cres.IndClassIT]: [@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper)]